# GWT - You cannot currently introduce new annotations in devmode. Please restart

Tags: java, gwt

I got this error while trying to compile my `GWT` app. I tried to Google it but there is no informative description of this error:

```
[ERROR] java.lang.RuntimeException: a new annotation has been introduced (org.hibernate.validator.constraints.ConstraintComposition); you cannot currently introduce new annotations in devmode. Please restart.
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.errai.config.rebind.MetaClassBridgeUtil.populateMetaClassFactoryFromTypeOracle(MetaClassBridgeUtil.java:88)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.errai.config.rebind.AbstractAsyncGenerator$2.run(AbstractAsyncGenerator.java:93)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.errai.config.rebind.AsyncGenerationJob.notifyStarting(AsyncGenerationJob.java:86)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.errai.config.rebind.AsyncGenerators.notifyStarting(AsyncGenerators.java:190)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.errai.config.rebind.AsyncGenerators.startAll(AsyncGenerators.java:144)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.errai.config.rebind.AsyncGenerators.getFutureFor(AsyncGenerators.java:55)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.errai.config.rebind.AsyncGenerationJob.submit(AsyncGenerationJob.java:109)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.errai.config.rebind.AbstractAsyncGenerator.startAsyncGeneratorsAndWaitFor(AbstractAsyncGenerator.java:86)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.errai.ioc.rebind.ioc.bootstrapper.IOCGenerator.generate(IOCGenerator.java:58)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.core.ext.IncrementalGenerator.generateNonIncrementally(IncrementalGenerator.java:40)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.StandardGeneratorContext.runGeneratorIncrementally(StandardGeneratorContext.java:657)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.RuleGenerateWith.realize(RuleGenerateWith.java:41)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle$Rebinder.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:79)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:276)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:265)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.DistillerRebindPermutationOracle.getAllPossibleRebindAnswers(DistillerRebindPermutationOracle.java:91)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.handleGwtCreate(UnifyAst.java:355)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.handleMagicMethodCall(UnifyAst.java:433)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.endVisit(UnifyAst.java:237)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodCall.traverse(JMethodCall.java:243)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:265)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:116)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JCastOperation.traverse(JCastOperation.java:65)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:265)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:116)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JDeclarationStatement.traverse(JDeclarationStatement.java:48)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor$ListContextImmutable.traverse(JModVisitor.java:170)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.acceptWithInsertRemoveImmutable(JModVisitor.java:336)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JBlock.traverse(JBlock.java:83)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:137)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:133)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JTryStatement.traverse(JTryStatement.java:60)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor$ListContextImmutable.traverse(JModVisitor.java:170)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.acceptWithInsertRemoveImmutable(JModVisitor.java:336)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JBlock.traverse(JBlock.java:83)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:137)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:133)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodBody.traverse(JMethodBody.java:82)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:265)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethod.visitChildren(JMethod.java:434)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethod.traverse(JMethod.java:403)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:265)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst.mainLoop(UnifyAst.java:900)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst.exec(UnifyAst.java:625)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:640)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaScriptCompiler.java:33)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:278)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:229)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:141)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:232)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:198)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:170)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:88)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:82)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:177)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This exception gets thrown whenever an annotation type can't be loaded. As the message says (and Thomas explained in his response), one scenario where this can happen is when you add a new annotation type during a Dev Mode session.

Another possible way to get this error is not having `org.hibernate.validator.constraints.ConstraintComposition` on your GWT compiler's classpath. Try compiling with `mvn -X gwt:compile` and take a look at the classpath used with the GWT compiler. Verify that your GWT compilation classpath includes a .jar with org/hibernate/validator/constraints/ConstraintComposition.class in it.

Comment: this is exactly what was needed to fix the issue

Answer (score 2):

DevMode (and the GWT Compiler BTW) resolves annotations from bytecode, not source code (to my knownledge, this is the only use of bytecode as source in GWT); so annotations you introduce in your source code can't be seen by DevMode until you restart it.

This is unless the generator that makes use of the annotations uses some tricks to actually load the recompiled bytecode. FYI, GIN used to suffer from this limitation, and starting with 2.0 it uses `ClassLoader` tricks to mitigate it.

Errai seems to have some tricks to detect you have changed the source code in ways that won't be seen by DevMode (in this case, I suppose by the Bean Validation generator built into GWT, so it cannot be changed to use similar tricskas GIN) and generates an error.

Comment: Is there a fix for this issue? When I do gwt:compile the gwt dev mode is shutdown/not running, so I do not understand this

Comment: not sure if I did fully understand your answer, when I am running gwt:compile this error shows up. That said, gwt dev mode is not running

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't notice that you were getting this during a compile. First things first: don't run `mvn gwt:compile` without doing first a `mvn process-classes`, because `gwt:compile` won't run javac on your code first. Better use `mvn package` (or `mvn prepare-package`), possibly with `-DskipTests`. Other than that, the error being specific to Errai, cf. Jonathan Fuerth's answer, he's an Errai developer.